# Convert .htaccess into Web.Config

Tags: windows

I have recently moved to a windows server, my .htaccess file doesn't work with the new server, how can i convert this into a webconfig file?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the [Url Rewrite Module 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=urlrewrite2), you can do it right from IIS Manager:

**[Your Website Name] >> URL Rewrite >> Import Rules**

More on [IIS website](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules)

Comment: this is shared hosting, i have no access to this tool

Comment: Install it locally then, or use other online tool.